# Backend superset code changes not showing

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, backend, apache-superset

i don't have that much experience and i'm trying to get around the superset code.

i'm stuck trying to make some little changes here and there and seeing it reflected in superset.

[changes made in backend, but not getting them in the front](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKARd.png)

for example, in `superset/views/utils.py`, any change in the payload in `bootstrap_user_data` does not reflect on the `data_bootstrap` the frontend recieves, not sure why.

I'm running the backend with `FLASK_ENV=development superset run -p 8088 --reload --debugger` and the front with `npm run dev-server` as per documentation instructions.

Can someone help me out? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem.
I had installed superset via `pip install apache-superset` instead of following the instructions, which point to installing it `via pip install -e .`

Found about it by adding a 1/0 to a python file and not seeing everything explode, so I knew there was a problem around there.